# Swapping branches and removing the old one

Tags: git

Not so long ago I had two branches, `master` and `dev`, when I thought to myself - whoa, I must have messed up `dev` branch.

So I used `git revert` to some previous commit and created new branch - `dev2`. I actually made a mistake and reverted to some commit from master, then checked out to the proper commit from `dev`, so the branch originates from the `master` branch. Which should not be a problem I guess.

Ok, so I have `dev` branch which is unpulled (I can't pull it - it's broken as I mentioned), and `dev2` branch which is ok and working but originates from master.

I want to remove `dev` branch, and rename `dev2` to `dev`. Removing `dev` branch tells me I can't because I have some unmerged changes (true), and I'm not sure if removing the branch will do some harm to my repo.

How do I safely swap these?

Comment: Two meta comments I would like to make: 1) get some sort of git tree visualizer such as [gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl) (Mac) or [gitg](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/) (Linux) — there's nothing like it to help avoid confusion. I almost never do anything that involves branching or merging without one. 2) Before doing anything even the slightest bit risky, do `git branch foo` to create a "checkpoint" named foo. This way, no matter how badly pear-shaped things get, you can always get back.

Answer (score 0):

Not reading too much into your story, its possible for you to do a git branch -D on dev to really delete it, then rename your dev2 to dev. Although its not clear to me whether you can pull dev into your dev branch, you might pull --rebase to put your changes on top of dev and then push back up - not sure because Im not following the whole story about things added/reverted and where they were done.

Answer (score 0):

To move dev out of the way so you can then rename dev2 -> dev you would:

git branch -m dev dev-broken

and then

git branch -m dev2 dev

That way you have the broken branch a little while longer until you decide to delete it.